# Wtform nested fields not populated with populate_obj

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

So I have this `DemandeForm` with nested `FormField`:

```
    AdressePrivee = FormField(AdresseForm, default=AdressePrivee())
```

with `Demande` model:

```
AdressePrivee = db.relationship(AdressePrivee, backref='Demande', lazy=False, uselist=False)
```

I have nested fields submitted in the HTML form:

```
AdressePrivee-RueEtNumero: Boulevard Bonivard 11
AdressePrivee-ComplementNom: 
AdressePrivee-ComplementAdresse: 
AdressePrivee-CasePostale: 01420
AdressePrivee-NPA: 
AdressePrivee-Localite: Seyssel
AdressePrivee-Pays: 2
```

And I call it with:

```
    form = DemandeForm(data=request.form)

    if form.validate():
        form.populate_obj(demande) # Here, demande.AdressePrivee should be populated
        db.session.add(demande)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Enregistré', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

But if I print it there, all entries are set to `None`, as if `demande.AdressePrivee` is only equal to `AdressePrivee()` empty object (log: `<AdressePrivee None None None>`), while `FormField`s should be set, with the nested fields logic, shouldn't they?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't use the constructor directly, you should use a factory.

```
AdressePrivee = FormField(AdresseForm, default=lambda: AdressePrivee())
```

I also think the attribute for transferring the form data of the request is called "formdata" not "data".

```
form = DemandeForm(formdata=request.form)
```

In the following a small example that worked for me.

```
class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

class Inquiry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    address_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('address.id', ondelete='cascade'),
        nullable=False
    )
    address = db.relationship('Address', backref='inquiry', lazy=False, uselist=False)


class AddressForm(FlaskForm):
    street = StringField('street', validators=[DataRequired()])

    def __init__(self, csrf_enabled=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(csrf_enabled=csrf_enabled, *args, **kwargs)

class InquiryForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    address = FormField(AddressForm, default=lambda: Address())


@app.route('/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create():
    item = Inquiry()
    form = InquiryForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(item)
        db.session.add(item)
        db.session.commit()

    items = Inquiry.query.all()
    return render_template('create.html', **locals())
```

I wish you every success in implementing your project and hope I was able to help you.